# Is there a way to run executable from powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have some process.exe which I want to run through the powershell script (.ps1), Is there a way to do that. The executable takes input parameters also.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Answer (score 2):

You want Start-Process. Use "Get-Help Start-Process -Full" to find out what you exactly need.

Probably something like this:

Start-Process notepad.exe -ArgumentList "arguments"

Answer (score 1):

Below is a TechNet article which will give you different ways of running executables in PowerShell and would be very helpful if you read.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Regards,

Kvprasoon